# how to handle item click on recyclerview for changing an item image?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview that gets data from server. I want to save every item in database when clicked and also change item image. I have problem in changing image of items. when I click an item multiple items get selected or when scrolling recyclerview item image will change unfortunately.
here is my adapter code

```
public class RepairItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RepairItemsAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<RepairItems> doctorsList;
    private List<RepairItems> doctorsListFiltered;
    private List<RepairItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ContactsAdapterListener listener;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private boolean flag_wishlist = true;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView cat_name, cat_id, price;
        public ImageView my_checkbox;
        public LinearLayout linear;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cat_name = view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            price = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            cat_id = view.findViewById(R.id.category_id);
            my_checkbox = view.findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);
            linear = view.findViewById(R.id.linear);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    listener.onContactSelected(doctorsListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public RepairItemsAdapter(Context context, List<RepairItems> doctorsList, ContactsAdapterListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.doctorsList = doctorsList;
        this.doctorsListFiltered = doctorsList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.checklist_items, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final RepairItems cat_main = doctorsListFiltered.get(position);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        holder.cat_name.setText(cat_main.getProducts_title());
        holder.cat_id.setText(cat_main.getProduct_id());
        holder.price.setText(cat_main.getProducts_price());

        holder.linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (db.getWishlist(cat_main.getProduct_id()) != null) {
                    db.deleteWishlist(Long.valueOf(cat_main.getProduct_id()));
                    holder.my_checkbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_box_empty);

                } else {
                    Wishlist w = new Wishlist(Long.parseLong(cat_main.getProduct_id()), cat_main.getProduct_id(), cat_main.getProducts_title(), Integer.parseInt(cat_main.getProducts_price()));
                    db.saveWishlist(w);
                    holder.my_checkbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_box_checked);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return doctorsListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    doctorsListFiltered = doctorsList;
                } else {
                    List<RepairItems> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (RepairItems row : doctorsList) {

                        // post_title match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for post_title or phone number match
                        if (row.getProducts_title().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    doctorsListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = doctorsListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                doctorsListFiltered = (ArrayList<RepairItems>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface ContactsAdapterListener {
        void onContactSelected(RepairItems doctors);

    }
}
```

Comment: view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    listener.onContactSelected(doctorsListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });

Comment: @alireza could you provide the code of `listener.onContactSelected()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recycler view creates every item accordingly to its dataset. so when you scroll it gets refreshed by its dataset and your UI changes have no track as you did not change it in your dataset.

Solution: you need to save a flag when you click on it so that when it gets fresh, the cell knows there is a change and according to this change you triggered what you want to do

Take a property in your data model like `isSelected` as boolean

```
final RepairItems cat_main = doctorsListFiltered.get(position);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        holder.cat_name.setText(cat_main.getProducts_title());
        holder.cat_id.setText(cat_main.getProduct_id());
        holder.price.setText(cat_main.getProducts_price());
        
        if(cat_main.isSelected){
            holder.my_checkbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_box_checked);
        }else{
            holder.my_checkbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_box_empty);
        }


        holder.linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (db.getWishlist(cat_main.getProduct_id()) != null) {
                    db.deleteWishlist(Long.valueOf(cat_main.getProduct_id()));
                    holder.my_checkbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_box_empty);

                } else {
                    Wishlist w = new Wishlist(Long.parseLong(cat_main.getProduct_id()), cat_main.getProduct_id(), cat_main.getProducts_title(), Integer.parseInt(cat_main.getProducts_price()));
                    db.saveWishlist(w);
                    holder.my_checkbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_box_checked);
                    doctorsListFiltered[position].isSelected=true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // send selected contact in callback
                listener.onContactSelected(doctorsListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        });
```

You have the above method in the constructor of the Viewholder class. May be that is causing  the problem. Instead have the holder.itemView.setOnClickListener() method inside onBindViewHolder() do the above task. That will solve your problem.